# Высота текста на элементе html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Если я установил шрифт размером `fontsz` (px), то что это означает? Будет ли это максимальной высотой символов?

Как подобрать высоту так чтобы черный прямоугольник полностью покрывал любой текст и чтобы внутренние границы до текста были минимальны? Если у вас получится это сделать, то почему границы будут минимальны?

```js
var can = $("canvas").get(0);
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

// x, y -- центр текста (???)
var fontsz = 100, x = 200, y = 100, font = `${fontsz}px Arial`;
ctx.font = font;

var str = "qw]gHC}";
var w = ctx.measureText(str).width;
var h = fontsz; // ???

ctx.fillRect(x-w/2, y-h/2, w, h);

ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillText(str, x, y);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

уберите Baseline, это точно поможет. Либо отметьте границу от верхней стороны.